# How to add user to another group in Ubuntu?

Tags: permissions, groups

My current groups:

```
chris@Host:/opt/tomcat$ groups
chris adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare
```

If I tried to add to group named `tomcat`:

```
$sudo usermod -a -G tomcat chris
```

but the group is not added, after viewing the `groups` command again:

```
chris adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare
```

simply no change. Why? I *can* see the my group be added to `tomcat's`:

cat `/etc/group`:

```
...

tomcat:x:1001:chris
```

But still I do not have permission from that group (so I am not in there). Why? How's that possible?

Comment: You will need to log out and back in (or at least start a new login session, with `su - chris` for example). See [Bionic - Group addition using usermod -aG doesn't take effect until the next reboot](https://askubuntu.com/a/1073129/178692) (but note that you **don't** need to go as far as rebooting).

Comment: @steeldriver thanks! Well simple logout/login did not helped. I actually went for reboot (then it worked). But thanks anyway